# Getting an Adsense account approved on a Meteor website

Tags: meteor, adsense

I am having difficulty getting approved with Adsense. It seems there is not enough content but I have many blog articles, no inappropriate content or copyright infringements and I have the Ad code in place within the footer.

I believe the issue may caused by my site using client side rendering. (Meteor javascript framework)
So this means that if I do:

```
$> curl http://www.dales-sports-media.com
```

I get mostly empty html (meta and html tags, but nothing in the body)

Sharing articles from my site to Facebook and Twitter seems to work fine

Is it possible that google's adsense approval bot is unable to see the fully rendered page?
Has anyone successfully applied for a Adsense account with a Meteor web app?

Thanks,
Mick

Comment: Asking how to get AdSense to approve your website is off-topic as it is about an external service policy, and we are not lawyers nor AdSense employees. What you should do instead is focus on the issue at hand - rendering server-side to serve HTML content instead of pure JS content. Please [edit] your question to make it on-topic.

Comment: Obviously the reason he speaks about the approval process is validate the 'why'. Otherwise people typically respond with 'And why would you want to do that?' wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [Prerender](http://prerender.io) which is a service that will render and cache your page(s), and then bots will be served up that version so they get the full HTML body.

You should set up nginx to be in front of your Meteor app, so that nginx will use `proxy_pass` to pass traffic from port 80 into your Meteor app on localhost port 3000, for example.

Then use this nginx config file as a guideline to set up Prerender: https://gist.github.com/thoop/8165802

If you're limited and can't install your own web server, make sure you've tried the [spiderable](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/spiderable) package.

```
$ meteor add spiderable
```

Comment: Thanks for the info @ffxsam. I think I could handle setting this up if my site was deployed onto an environment like Amazon or Rackspace where I have more control. However, this is deployed to Heroku. The build pack apparently includes phantom js. This was to allow sharing on social media sites without suffering from the same problem. Are you aware of a way I can achieve this configuration on a provider like Heroku where I don't have access to nginx?

Comment: Hmm, so you're limited, and PhantomJS is available. Have you tried `meteor add spiderable` yet?

Comment: Does this help re nginx and Heroku? https://blog.codeship.com/how-to-deploy-nginx-on-heroku/

Comment: I have posted message on the AdSense Help Forum and this is the response: It looks like all your content is wrapped in javascript. Adsense uses text crawlers to review a website because it's contextual advertising (requires text readable by text browsers). A text crawler can't execute javascript, so they aren't going to be able to read the content.

This tool shows the content seen by the browser:

https://varvy.com/tools/ - Thanks everyone for you help...